# Generics or inheritance/Interface in Java?

Tags: java, generics

```
class Product<T>{
   String name;

   T category;
}
```

Compared with the design below, which one is better and how to choose which in different situations? I feel they are the same or very similar in terms of functionality.

```
class Product{
  String name;
  Category category;
}

interface Category {
   String type();
}

class C1 implements Category{
    ...
   @Override
   String type(){
      ...   
   }
}

class C2 implements Category{
    ...
   @Override
   String type(){
      ...   
   }
}
```

Comment: They do different things. The generic version specifies a component type without restriction on the type. The inheritance version specifies a specific type. No restriction vs. specific type is pretty different. Use no restriction when you don't need to restrict the component type. Use a specific type when you need the specific type.

Comment: *"Generics or inheritance/Interface in Java?"* ... Yes.

Comment: You should add a restriction to the first example: `class Product<T extends Category>`. With that design Methods can define a Compile-Time restriction ("I only want Products of the Category X"): `public void anyMethod(Product<? extends C2> product)` which can be pretty nice to develop with

Comment: If you need the possibility to get, say, a `C2` out of a `Product<C2>`, then prefer the generic version. The second version can only give you a `Category`. If this or something similar is not a requirement, try with second, the non-generic solution for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a third way that you could do this, that I personally would choose:

```
interface Product
{
    public String getName();
    public String getCategory();
}

class Shirt implements Product
{
    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return "Shirt";
    }

    @Override
    public String getCategory()
    {
        return "Clothing";
    }
}
```

The reason I would suggest this way is that you are likely going to have different types of products, e.g. shirts, jeans, underwear, a bottle of milk. These should probably have an `is a` relationship with `Product`, i.e. a shirt is a product, and a bottle of milk is a product. This indicates that `Shirt` will either inherit from some base `Product` class:

```
class Product
{
    String name;
    String category;
}
```

Or, it will implement a `Product` interface:

```
interface Product
{
    public String getName();
    public String getCategory();
}
```

Both ways will work, I like the interface more because it doesn't limit you to a single parent. Now, every product can have much more specific attributes as well - for example, a shirt will have a size, while a bottle of milk will have a certain volume:

```
class MilkBottle implements Product
{
    int volume;

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return "Milk (" + volume + "ml)";
    }

    @Override
    public String getCategory()
    {
        return "Grocery";
    }
}
```

> Which one is better and how to choose which in different situations?

It's pretty hard, if not impossible, to prove that one solution is better than another when it comes to coding. It is a judgment call that you have to make, and you get better with experience. That being said, there are two things you should always consider:

- How easy will this solution be to use?
- How easy will this solution be to maintain?

Start implementing a small mock-up of your solutions, and see for yourself which one you think works better. Is it easy to instantiate a product? Or to unit test the classes? How about 3 months later, when you decide to add a new product?

I hope this helps you in the future.

Comment: This is great. I finally came up with a solution like this, after spending hours on attempting to use generics to solve my problem. It seems generics involves more complexity.

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading the question, I think I understand what you are asking a bit better - how do you decide whether to make a member generic, or use an interface? I'll leave my first answer, in case you feel it has some relevance, but here is a more specific answer.

Say I have an 'Order' class, which contains a product, and the quantity to purchase.

```
class Order
{
    Product product;
    int quantity;
}
```

What happens if I make that a generic parameter of the `Order` class instead?

```
class GenericOrder<P>
{
    P product;
    int quantity;
}
```

As @rollback pointed out in the comments, `product` could be anything! It could be a `Shirt`, or it could be an `int`. The only thing that we can guarantee about the type `P` is that it inherits from `Object`. We need to add some constraints, so that `P` must be some class that inherits from (or implements) `Product`.

```
class GenericOrder<P extends Product>
{
    P product;
    int quantity;
}
```

Now, these two solutions are almost identical, in terms of what they achieve. `GenericOrder` is a bit more flexible than plain old `Order`, because you can have a method which takes only an order for shoes:

```
public int availableShoeBoxes(GenericOrder<Shoe> order)
{
    ...
```

You just can't do that with a plain old `Order`, so if you (or anyone else using your code) need that use case, then you should use the generic type.

One downside to the `GenericOrder` is that you have to specify the `P` type every time you want to use it:

```
GenericOrder<Shirt> order = new GenericOrder<>(shirt, quantity);
```

If you don't need to be able to do operations on orders of a specific type, I would recommend going with the `Order` type, for the sake of simplicity. If at some point in the future, you find yourself needing the features of the generic version, it is not hard to refactor it in an IDE.

Comment: "in the future, ... it is not hard to refactor it" Once one's published an API, i.e., client code is using it, it's very hard to refactor it if one changes what that code uses. Making a type generic suddenlys causes existing code to break with unchecked warnings. One has to modify existing code to adopt the changes. Be very thoughtful before committing to an API.

Comment: Can it be defined like this: class GenericOrder<? extends Product>{}?

Comment: @user697911 When you use the question mark, it basically means 'I don't really care what type this is, because I'm not going to refer to it directly'. This makes it rather pointless in a class _declaration_, because you can't have variables of the specific type. It's more useful when you are _using_ the type. In the very last example above, `GenericOrder<Shirt> order` could be replaced by `GenericOrder<? extends Product> order`, to indicate that I don't care what type of product is being sold.

Comment: @LewBloch Yes, if you plan to release the class as part of an API, I would be more inclined to start with the generic version, so that end users can have more flexibility if they need it.

Comment: Any type used by any other type is an API.

Comment: Yeah I guess API is a pretty broad term, too late to edit the comment. How about 'If you plan to use the class in more than one project'